# Why am I getting "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota" when I have maximum quotas (YouTube API)

Tags: youtube-api

I just created a project in Developer portal.
I am trying to make a request in YouTube API playground, but getting this error:
"The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota".
I just created a project and haven't used any quota yet.
Why is this happening?

[image]

I expect my request to be executed without any errors.
Related threads stuck in calculating quotas, but I have max quotas and still getting this error.

Here are my quotas:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: If your project isn't approved it will have 0 quota. Check your quota in your Google Console.

Comment: Looks like I have plenty. Please see the screenshot.

Comment: Hmmm. then maybe verify you are actually using your API key, and not [YOUR_API_KEY] like the 1st screenshot.